# How to access images from CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, coffeescript

I am attempting to access the image: app/assets/images/rails/png, in my CoffeeScript file but using

`<img src='assets/images/rails.png' width='30' height='30'>`

yields the console error:

[image]

How can I access the images stored in my images file from CoffeeScript?

Comment: @muistooshort With the change to /assets/images/rails.png, the error is `http://localhost:3000/assets/images/rails.png ` cannot be found, how can I get it to work

Comment: Have you looked at what `asset_path` does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your CoffeeScript file's extension from *.js.coffee* to *.js.coffee.erb*. After that you can do this(wherever you want to use images that are present in your *assets/images* directory:

```
'<%= asset_path 'rails.png' %>'
```

Note the single-quote: `'`, it is important because URL would be: `/assets/rails.png` and you would want it to present as a string. This saves you time of figuring out why you're getting some weird JavaScript undefined constant error.

Comment: I decided to add the images to the public folder, it worked out that way. Thank you